How can a Lenovo ThinkPad get the power rating from a power supply with only a two-pin connector?
If the question is the same as How smart are laptop power bricks for Lenovo Thinkpads? I apologize, but I'm not familiar with "power bricks".
I have a Lenovo ThinkPad that requires significant power, so it was delivered with a 170W power supply.
When I bought the corresponding Thunderbolt docking station that one arrived with a 300W power supply.
Both provide power through a rectangular 2-pin (as it seems to me) connector:

Here is a more detailed image of the connector (both plugs are actually the same size, but the wide angle lens distorts the sizes a lot):

Now the point is:
One day I was lazy (the 170W power supply was just in reach) and used the 170W power supply to power the docking station (which in turn powers the ThinkPad using the same connector, i.e. not Thunderbold (as that is limited to about 100W for ThinkPads, it seems)).
Even thought he laptop was more or less idle (and thus expected to need much less than 170W), Windows complained that the power supply would not be strong enough.
So I wonder:
How can the ThinkPad detect the maximum power of a power supply connected via two pins (also through a docking station) while it only uses little power?
I mean: I could understand if the ThinkPad would try to draw more power than the supply can deliver (and the voltage goes down), but not in the situation desribed.

There may be a third pin hidden somewhere in there. It looks like at least one of the sides on the inside might be metal?

@Hearth exactly that's the case!

@Hearth Sorry, I inspected the plug very carefully after reading this, but I could not find a third contact: Inside the yellow plug all is plastic, except the pin in the middle, so there's just the outside and the middle pin.

@U.Windl There are ways to multiplex data onto a power line, and I guess that must be what it's doing here, then. I'm not sure what else it could be doing.

it could simply notice the voltage drop when it tries to pull as much power as it can. It could also provide slightly different voltages from different power ratings and detect that.

..or it could implement the powerline protocol ;-) I mean: we could speculate a lot while not knowing...

@U.Windl We don't have to speculate, we know for a fact. See my answer.

See https://superuser.com/a/1246834/511090 on SuperUser.

@Transistor Yes, Chester Gillon said the same before as comment for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/731677/282833

Answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/731677/282833 is correct, but as I wanted to provide some details, I did not want to edit that answer massively, but instead build on that answer, so here it goes:
Even if is seems the two pins are "outside" and "middle pin", there are actually three pins on the "Slim Tip" connector.
The second pin is inside the shorter sides of the connector (I had to use a better camera to show):

Looking at the counter-part of the "Thunderbolt 4 Workstation Dock", there are three contacts also:

1 is for the outside contact (ground) pressing inside, 2 is for the inside contact (20V) pressing outside, and 3 is the middle (sense) contact.
As explained in https://superuser.com/a/1246834 a resistor between ground and the sense pin indicates the power rating of the AC adapter.
I measured these values for the two AC adapters mentioned in the question:

The 170W AC adapter shows 1.9kΩ resistance
The 300W/20V AC adapter shows 8.7kΩ resistance

Unfortunately things get more complicated when using the "Thunderbolt 4 Workstation Dock", because the AC adapter is connected to the dock, while a "Thunderbolt 4 Split Cable" serves as a power and dock connection for the laptop:
The "output" to the laptop:

The "input" to the cable:

The "Round Tip" connector has three pins also (the middle pin cannot be seen in the photo):

Again both ends use three pins, but the cable itself is "straight through", i.e.: there is no resistor between pins 1 and 3, and on the "Thunderbolt 4 Workstation Dock" output there is no resistor between pins 1 and 3 also.
So how does the laptop know the power rating of the AC adapter then?
I can only guess that the "Thunderbolt 4 Workstation Dock" makes the value from the AC adapter available through the Thunderbolt 4 cable.

Unlikely negotiated through Thunderbolt. The power connector is a custom plug on a custom cable so the resistor is likely built into the plug. Like it likely is on your charger plug too. Having three wires between plug and charger simply to indicate available power would be waste of expensive copper, resistor inside plug makes more sense.

As I described: the output from the dock to the laptop has no resistor (ie.: infinite resistance) between ground and sense on output, so the laptop cannot know that way. And the only other way is the Thunderbolt connection. Maybe it's cheaper to have fewer different cables and plugs for manufacturing. Given the price of the dock, I think that little copper is not actually relevant.

There may be active electronics in the plugs. Or in the dock that it enables a resistor when it knows how much there is available from supply so it must show less to laptop. Like with USB-C cables, the ID pin between dock and laptop could become a data pin.

@Justme Do you know, or do you speculate? I have the hardware, and I measured it, so what can you do to prove your claims?

Did you tear the hardware down to see how it works? Did you measure the hardware under operation or without power? I can see multiple reasons why the measurements may not be valid.  Your dock needs to tell the laptop how much power is available, even without Thunderbolt, when it is off with dead battery, to know how much it can pull from DC plug. The dock needs to be able to tell that based on how large supply dock has, and must vary which resistance it shows. And it may wait for laptop to pull the pin high first. Lenovo has also used 1-wire communications, like DS2501 for digital ID in PSU.

@Justme You are free to do so (tear down the hardware): As a matter of fact there is no connection between the ground and the sense pin of the dock's power output when input power is provided! I measured it, especially because you didn't believe that I was right. You tell a lot of things, but that dock is the Thunderbolt Dock intended to be used with a Thunderbolt connection (or maybe USB Power Delivery, too). -- However you are free to prove me that I'm wrong, but please stop speculating what might be...

Your assumption that the connector has only two pins is wrong.
The square barrel has power contacts on inside and outside, which is very typical for modern connectors for laptops and other devices.
The pin at the center is simply an ID pin which the power supply uses to tell the laptop how powerful it is.

I found this Super User answer which shows the resistor values used for the ID pin of Lenovo Trim Yellow rectangular power adapter

The contacts on the inside are hidden very well; I needed a magnifying glass to see them.
